# configuring ruby for emacs on Windows

Tags: ruby, emacs

I am trying to build a project on ruby, using Emacs for editor. 
I can see that the ruby mode is activated when I create a .rb file, but I would like to be eable to evaluate the code interactively (a bit like C-x C-e with Emacs Lisp). Is there a way to plug irb inside emacs for that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `inf-ruby` (written by Matz himself):

http://rinari.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/test/lisp/inf-ruby.el

Comment: OK, I have installed inf-ruby (and rinari as well). However, when I try the ruby-mode, it says that irb can't be find, and I dont see where in the file inf-ruby.el I can tell emacs where my ruby repertory is.

Comment: OK, I am *really* an idiot. All I had to do was to add the repertory where my ruby binaries are in my PATH environmental variable.